# RegEx - Find everything that does not contain a pattern

Tags: regex

I got this regex code:

```
((\w)(\w)\3\2)
```

It matches everything that contains something like anna, otto, xyyx ...

But I want to match everything that does NOT contain such a pattern.
How can i do that?

Comment: Depends on the regex flavor and what you want to do. Please add details.

Comment: Regex is not useful for this kind of needs. You will have to code the "does not contain" in your programmation language, which is pretty more simpler that a Regex "does not contain".

Comment: Just split using this pattern and join later with the string method.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has already been raised on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word). You should try this :

```
^((?!(\w)(\w)\3\2).)*$
```

Comment: This only matches a whole line/string that does not contain the pattern but not anything that does not match the pattern.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for _anything that does not match the pattern_, but for _everything that does not **contain** a pattern._ The sensible interpretation of _thing_ in this case is _line_, thus this answer is perfectly right.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought this kind of does what you are asking.  But for the reasons raised by @WiktorStribiżew below it does not work.  In particular test strings such as AAAB and ABBC are supposed to match the below but *do not*

```
^((\w)(\w)(?!\3)(?!\2))
```

My second thought is to use

```
^((\w)(\w)(?!\3\2))
```

And this does seem to work.

New test program.  This generates all possible strings from AAAA to ZZZZ.  Then a non regexp check is used to test if each string should match or not.  Finally, each string is checked for compliance against both the positive

$findrepeats, `^((\w)(\w)(\3)(\2))` matches abba

and the negative

$repeatnomatch `^((\w)(\w)(?!\3)(?!\2))` matches ab[not b][not a]

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fourchar=('AAAA'..'ZZZZ'); 

my @norepeats=();

my @hasrepeats=();

for my $pattern ('AAAA' .. 'ZZZZ') {
  if (checkstring($pattern)) {
    push @hasrepeats, $pattern;
    } else {
    push @norepeats, $pattern;
    }
}

print scalar @hasrepeats, " strings with repeated abba\n";
print scalar @norepeats, " strings with ab[not b][not a]\n";



my $findsrepeats=qr/^((\w)(\w)(\3)(\2))/;
my $repeatnomatch=qr/^((\w)(\w)(?!\3\2))/;

for my $example (@hasrepeats) {
  die $example if (not($example=~$findsrepeats));
  die $example if ($example=~$repeatnomatch);
}

for my $example (@norepeats) {
  die $example if (not($example=~$repeatnomatch));
  die $example if ($example=~$findsrepeats);
}

print "pass\n";

sub checkstring {
  my $s=shift;
  my @element=split(//,$s);
  return ($element[0] eq $element[3]  && 
          $element[1] eq $element[2]);
}
```

Running the above perl program should produce this output

```
$ perl nr3.pl 
676 strings with repeated abba
456300 strings with ab[not b][not a]
pass
```

Comment: This is incorrect. When do you think `(?!\2)` is executed?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would guess it is evaluated left to right, so the capture groups are set first and then the negative look-ahead assertions are done after this.  The test program seems to work as I'd expect, so if you could give me strings that give false negatives or positives it might help me to understand this further.  Thanks

Comment: Your assumptions are correct but if you plan to match `ab[not-b][not-a]`, this regex won't do, because lookaheads are executed at the same place, after `b`. `(?!\2)` checks if the character after `b` is not `a`. The fourth character can be any.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok I've managed to figure out how to replicate what you are saying.  If I feed a string like "AAAB" ``^((\w)(\w)(?!\3)(?!\2))`` does not match but it should.  I am rewriting the answer